# How to scale up and down and keep aspect ratio?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale

I want to keep the aspect ratio of the white square and the green rectangle above it in both portrait and landscape mode while they fill either width or height.

[image: What it looks like]

In the canvas, I've selected `Scale With Screen Size` and `Match width or height` of `0.5` value.

[image: Canvas settings]

And `Board` GameObject is anchored to the center

[image: Canvas element settings]

The problem is that it keeps aspect ratio but goes out of screen when it doesn't fit.

**Update:**
It's anchored to the middle center:
[image]

**Update 2:**
After setting anchor to `min(0,0),max(1,1)` now the `Board` is stretched inside the `Canvas` but inner images keep their size and go out of screen in landscape mode:

(Inside `Canvas Scaler` component of `Canvas`, I changed `Match` value from `0.5` to `1 Height`. Now it scales down the height. It works for most of the screen sizes I see, but on very tall screens, the sides go out of screen.)
[image]

Comment: Can you expand the Anchors section of the Board object and take a new screenshot? The anchors are important here.

Comment: @Draco18s Please check the last screenshot.

Comment: By anchoring it to the middle center you've said "don't scale this object when the parent scales." Set it to `min(0,0),max(1,1)`

Comment: @Draco18s I tried, please check the updated screenshot